# DELL IDrac 6 IPMI query - Ambient Tempearture

Tags: ipmitool

I am connected up to my Idrac however, when asking for the ambient temp, I get no value. I am using this command:

Ipmitool -I Lanplus -H x.x.x.x -U xxxx -P xxxxxx sensor reading "Ambient Temp"

I believe this is because there are actually 3 values for ambient temp where the first 2 are disabled sensors (think they are the power supplies).
If I do a sdr entity 7.1 I get just the one ambient temp in the list of all 7.1 sensors.

So the question is, how do I construct a command to get the sensor reading for all entity 7.1 sensors where the name is Ambient Temp?
[image]

Note that I am doing this on a Windows machine.
Thanks.